# Hero image with overlapping text box content appearing behind text box. How can I fix without using media queries?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a hero image that has a text box overlapping the hero a little bit but when I add any content below the box it appears under the text box. Some media queries are added in my code below and it works but I feel like there has to be a way to contain the hero and overlapping text box into its own section. If had to add more text I'd have to go through and adjust all of the media queries to make it look good again so how can I achieve this without using media queries?

Here is my code:

```css
.shell {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

/* overlap */

.shell:before {
  content: "";
  background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/x866XdV/test-hero.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: bottom;
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}

.shell-header {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0px 20px;
}

.shell-body {
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  background-color: #fff;
  max-width: 85%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 80%;
}
img {
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  padding-top: 12rem;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  .wrapper {
    padding-top: 8rem;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 360px) {
  .wrapper {
    padding-top: 11rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="shell">
  <div class="shell-header"></div>
  <div class="shell-body">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat vel ducimus illo consectetur commodi ex nulla aut amet ipsum maiores itaque, iusto quam mollitia facilis consequatur tempora neque quod eligendi?</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3f/Placeholder_view_vector.svg" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `padding` is ideal. But you can play around with the positioning of your elements. For instance, you can set `body` to `position: relative;` & then nest `.wrapper` within `.shell` and set `.wrapper` to `position: absolute;`.

```css
.shell {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

/* overlap */

.shell:before {
  content: "";
  background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/x866XdV/test-hero.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: bottom;
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}

.shell-header {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0px 20px;
}

.shell-body {
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  background-color: #fff;
  max-width: 85%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 80%;
}

img {
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="shell">
  <div class="shell-header"></div>
  <div class="shell-body">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat vel ducimus illo consectetur commodi ex nulla aut amet ipsum maiores itaque, iusto quam mollitia facilis consequatur tempora neque quod eligendi?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3f/Placeholder_view_vector.svg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Example using negative `margin`.

```css
.shell {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}


/* overlap */

.shell:before {
  content: "";
  background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/x866XdV/test-hero.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: bottom;
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}

.shell-header {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0px 20px;
}

.shell-body {
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  background-color: #fff;
  max-width: 85%;
  margin-top: -6.375rem;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

img {
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper {
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="shell">
  <div class="shell-header"></div>
  <div class="shell-body">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat vel ducimus illo consectetur commodi ex nulla aut amet ipsum maiores itaque, iusto quam mollitia facilis consequatur tempora neque quod eligendi?</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3f/Placeholder_view_vector.svg" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: It will still require a manual change of the number which normally would be fine but the CMS I use allows users to input text without any coding experience which would cause problems if they add text and can't change that number. I found this site that has the same thing but looking on inspect I can't figure out how they are doing it. https://www.rescue.org/

Comment: @canijusttravel That site is accomplishing it by using a negative `margin`. See edits for an updated example.

Comment: The negative margin works! Thank you!